# Send audio output to all speaker devices

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, audio, core-audio

I need to be able to direct sound output from my application to *all* of a system's audio outputs - specifically, both the built-in speakers and headphones of a laptop. I'm using C# on Windows Vista/7 and the latest version of the .NET Framework, and don't need to support older (i.e. Windows XP) OSes.

I was able to successfully use the [Core Audio API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx) to change the volume for the active speakers, and was able to enumerate and specifically manipulate individual audio devices, but was unable to actually change the state of the devices to enable them.

```
private MMDeviceEnumerator devEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
private MMDeviceCollection audioDevices = null;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.defaultDevice = this.devEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
    AudioEndpointVolumeNotificationDelegate(AudioEndpointVolume_OnVolumeNotification);
    this.audioDevices = this.devEnum.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(EDataFlow.eRender, EDeviceState.DEVICE_STATEMASK_ALL);
    for (int i = 1; i < this.audioDevices.Count; i++)
    {
        // Doesn't work - throws exception because property is read-only:
        // this.audioDevices[i].State = EDeviceState.DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE 
    }
}
```

Basically, what I am looking for is a way to enable audio devices, not just adjust their volume. Does anybody know of a way to do this? I've been looking at the MSDN Documentation for [IMMDevice Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679028.aspx) but am finding it difficult since it's not offered as managed code, and the .NET wrapper I'm using doesn't fully implement it. I'm also open to suggestions that take a completely different approach, as long as I can still do it using C#. Thanks!

Comment: Even if you can enable different devices, like a bluetooth headset and built-in speakers, you're unlikely to be able to play sound through speakers when earphones are plugged in -- this is usually purely electrical -- mechanically inserting the earphone jack routes the audio to the inserted device instead of the speakers. As far as the computer is concerned, it is all one device.

Comment: Without knowing what API you're using to render audio, it's hard to know how to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure the devices you want sound from are enabled in Windows sound control panel, then they will all show as DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE. If you want to send the same audio file to play on multiple devices the same time, you should be able to do that with the Core Audio API. But if you want to control other applications to force them to play to all those outputs, you would have to rewrite their code ;P You could make a low level driver that would intercept all sound going out and then redirect it to all the devices you want. Something like http://ac3filter.net/ (although ac3Filter only works if the app uses DirectShow I think)

Comment: ac3filter does not "intercept all sound going out", it just outputs a multi-channel audio stream. If you have a multichannel sound card you will hear "something" in al your speakers.